# Flutter app not building (Android studio)

Tags: flutter

My Flutter app throws an error when I am trying to run it.

> Compiler message:
>   org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
>   context
>   ^^^^^^^
>
> org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Getter not found: 'initialDate'.
>   initialDate
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> Compiler failed on F:\FlutterProjects\myDemoProject\lib\main.dart
>   Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

It was running before few minutes. I have not changed anything inside the main.dart even thought it is throwing exception form main.dart. Below is my main.dart.

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new CupertinoApp(
    title: 'App Name',
    home: new RootPage(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/home': (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(),
      '/signin': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
    });
  }
```

OS: Windows 10
IDE: Android Studio

Please help

Comment: Try cleaning the project. In cmd navigate to your project root and try `flutter clean`

Comment: What about restart the Android Studio and re-open the project...?

Comment: I invalidated the cash and restarted the android studio but it did not resolve the issue. The flutter clean I will try today.

Comment: @Blasanka flutter clean worked for me. Thanks everyone for your time and help!

Answer (score 4):

Try running `flutter clean` in the root directory of your flutter project. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue for a while now but i fixed it by installing [gradle](https://gradle.org/)

Comment: Could be helpful to include commands to run in your answer